# Javascript, getting global variable property

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is set a global variable dot type to "mobile" or "desktop" according to the screen size.

`var userScreen = {}`

```
if (screen is small){
  userScreen.type === 'mobile'
}
else {
  userScreen.type === 'desktop'
}
```

Everything is working within the same file but I'm having issues getting the userScreen.type to be available in another JavaScript file.

**screen-size.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var userScreen = {};

  var resizeTimer;
  $(window).on('resize load', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      var windowWidth = $(window).width();
      if ($('body').height() < $(document).height()) {
        var windowWidth = windowWidth + 15;
      }
      if (windowWidth < 768){
        userScreen.type = 'mobile';
      }
      else{
        userScreen.type = 'desktop';
      } 
    }, 250);
  });
```

**another-js-file**

```
$(document).ready(function(userScreen){
  console.log(userScreen.type);
});
```

Console Log "userScreen.type" result:

```
function( obj ) {
    if ( obj == null ) {
        return obj + "";
    }
    // Support: Android<4.0, iOS<6 (functionish RegExp)
    return typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function" ?
        class2type[ t…
```

Load order:

1. screen-size.js
2. another-js-file.js

Thanks

**EDIT**

Want to say thank you for everyones responses. Final answer

So I created an IIFE with just setting the `window.userScreen` object

**get-user-screen.js**

```
window.userScreen = {};

function getScreenSize(){
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if ($('body').height() < $(document).height()) {
    var windowWidth = windowWidth + 15;
  }
  if (windowWidth < 768){
    userScreen.type = 'mobile';
  }
  else{
    userScreen.type = 'desktop';
  }
  console.log(userScreen.type);
}

(function(){
  getScreenSize();
}());
```

That made the variable available globally like I wanted and eliminated the Timeout issue that was brought up. Everything is working as expected.

Thanks again

Comment: The userScreen is not a global variable. It exists in $(document).ready scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to declare an explicit global is to create it directly on the `window` object. So for your case, create it like:

`window.userScreen = {};`

And when you want to access it, you can again do it via `window.userScreen`. Many might object to this usage because globals do smell however this is a way to obviously communicate to another developer that your global is an intentional global.

I advocate for using a better pattern like CommonJS modules but that does require more setup and knowledge. But if you're curious, it's a great direction to go if you want to keep your code clean and compartmentalized.

Comment: Trying to get better at compartmentalizing and yes it's very intentional variable. Thanks for explaining and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable in your html, before you load any js files, inside a script tag. Like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' > 
  var userScreen = {}; 
</script>
```

Put that before the script tags that load your javascript files, and they should all be able to use that variable. Also, remember not to redeclare that variable again; remove the `var userScreen = {};` from inside screen-size.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply, trying to avoid setting anything in the markup

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare it outside the document.ready (as global variable).
Secondly, You're getting the *userScreen.type* before you're setting it (see timeout 250). I'd suggest different approach, from your description i don't see any point in having a timeout. Therefor:

**screen-size.js**

```
function getSize(){
  if ($('body').height() < $(document).height()) {
    var windowWidth = windowWidth + 15;
  }
  if (windowWidth < 768){
    return 'mobile';
  }
  else{
    return 'desktop';
  } 
}
```

**another-js-file.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(getSize());
});
```

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing that now, have to set up some type of promise to run when that value becomes available.